# The graph of congruences between modular forms

Tags: modular-forms, nt.number-theory, graph-theory

Let $S$ be the (countable) set of holomorphic cuspidal new eigenforms of weight $\geq 2$. Any $f\in S$ has a level $N_f$ and a canonically normalized Fourier expansion $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_f(n)e^{2\pi i nz}$ with $a_f(1)=1$ and $a_f(n) \in \overline{\mathbf{Z}}$.

Form a graph $\mathcal{G}$ as follows: Take the vertex set of $\mathcal{G}$ to be the set $S$, and join $f$ and $g$ by an edge if the algebraic integers $(a_f(n)-a_g(n))_{n \nmid N_f N_g}$ generate a nontrivial ideal in $\overline{\mathbf{Z}}$; in other words, $f$ and $g$ are joined if their Fourier coefficients are related by a nontrivial congruence.

Is $\mathcal{G}$ connected?

Comment: It would be interesting to ask the same question but requiring the ideal to be nontrivial in $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}[1/N]$. 

Comment: Wanax, you are correct to guess that I'm working with Ash.  But the answer below was written by The Hamburglar, not by me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ has level $N$, and suppose that $N$ is divisible by $p$.
Then it is well known that $f$ is congruent modulo (some prime above) $p$ to a form
$g$ of level $M$ dividing $N$ (and high weight), where $M$ is prime to $p$.
In particular, by induction, all forms $f$ are connected to a form $g$ of level $1$ in
at most $d$ steps, where $d$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $N$. Yet all
level one forms are congruent to $\Delta$ modulo $2$. This is actually related to ideas behind the proof of Serre's conjecture:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%27s_modularity_conjecture

Comment: @Wanax: you know, there is an edit history where you could check who actually said what. 

Comment: @quid:  where is this edit history you speak of?

Comment: This answer was written by The Hamburglar (who, by the way, I think is the same person behind the users Frictionless Jellyfish and Trust Me, and I think I know who it is in real life, but this margin won't contain it.)  I edited a trivial misprint; did that automatically convert it to a CW status?